# Sphericity. Mauchly's W of 1.000, df 0, and Sig of . . Nothing

Tags: sphericity

The question is about sphericity of repeated measures ANOVA (2 within factors)x(3 between factors). When I check for violations of the sphericity assumption Mauchly's test of sphericity gives me a Mauchly's W of 1.000, df 0, and Sig of . . Nothing. it gives me no sig. data.

Why would that be?

Comment: Zero degrees of freedom for a test doesn't sound good...

Comment: ok. Any idea why this could happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there are only 2 'within' factors. The test looks for variation in differences between levels of that factor, but when there are only two levels, there's only *one* relevant difference, leaving no remaining degrees of freedom to estimate any variation.  Consequently things break.

Here's an example, pilfered from the [wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauchly's_sphericity_test) on the test.

Start with three levels of treatment applied to each patient, and consider the variation in the differences between them

```
           Treatments     Treatment differences
Patient    A    B    C    A−B  A−C   B−C
      1   30   27   20      3   10     7
      2   35   30   28      5    7     2
      3   25   30   20     -5    5    10
      4   15   15   12      0    3     3
      5    9   12    7     −3    2     5

Variance:                  17   10.3  10.3
```

Mauchly's test tests whether the 17, 10.3, and 10.3 are all plausibly generated from a single true variance (the null hypothesis) rather than possibly different ones.

But consider the same situation with only A and B levels to the treatment:

```
           Treatments    Treatment differences
Patient    A    B        A−B  
      1   30   27          3 
      2   35   30          5 
      3   25   30         −5 
      4   15   15         12 
      5    9   12          7 

Variance:                 17
```

Is 17 plausibly the result of a single true variance? Yup! But trivially so, because even if there would have been variation across treatment levels, without more levels we can't estimate it what it would have been.